# If statement with conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, conditional-statements, abstract-data-type

Is there any way to make the following if statement more elegant without the need to repeat the "and" conditional  ? Sorry I m a newbie.

```
a = ' 10 20 30 40 50  '
print(a)
if '10' and '20' and '30' and '40' and '50' not in a :
    print('something is wrong')
else:
    print('This is correct')
```

Thanks

Comment: could you add the programming language among the tags?

Comment: are you trying to test  using strings or do you want to test using an array of numbers?

Comment: @LhasaDad,  I m actually trying to test strings , since I have quite few elements to evaluate , I would rather seek a simpler syntax as opposed to a sequence of "and".Thanks

Comment: The and syntax is not going to do it for you.  its not doing anything like what you want.   I am trying to think if a regular expression of the right form might work.  not seeing it yet but will play and see if I can come up with something and come back.

Comment: Ok, have an answer for you...

Answer (score 0):

Try this for size.  should check all the matches strings being in the a_string and if not the case print "something is wrong".

```
a_string = "10 20 30 40 50"
matches = ["10", "20", "30", "40", "50"]

if not all(x in a_string for x in matches):
   print('something is wrong')
else:
   print('This is correct')
```

Comment: Worked like a charm . Much appreciated

Comment: Thanks @Peaceandlove please upvote  the answer if you get a chance